# Cleaning 'cement' from grill

Tags: grilling, maintenance, charcoal, grill

I've been a bit lazy in the last couple of weeks and left some ash in my grill. I was cleaning it today and noticed a hard cement-like substance. I believe this is the dreaded corrosive 'cement' I've read about which is the result of ashes absorbing moisture.

I've scrubbed it with paper towels but it's not coming off.

Any recommendations on how to clean it?

Comment: What kind of grill is it? What material is the ash stuck to?

Comment: It's a steel grill.

Comment: IN your grill?  ...where the coals go?   ...or ON your grill, where the food goes?

Comment: In the grill where the charcoal goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is just steel then a stiff brush ought to do it, or steel wool. I'd be tempted to hose it down a few times, the water ought to loosen the ash before sponging it off. If there are coatings on it then using getting it wet makes the most sense as abrasives could damage the coatings.